# User.findOneAndUpdate not returning the updated user object

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

This is my updateUser controller function. It's not returning the updated object, even after setting `{new: true}` and `{useFindAndModify: false}` in the MongoDB connection in app.js. I'm only getting the same object whose **id** I am passing through the params.

```js
       updateUser: (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.params, "update user")
        User.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, { new: true }, (err, updatedUser) => {
            console.log(updatedUser)
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: "server error" })
            } else if (!updatedUser) {
                return res.status(400).json({ error: "No user found" })
            } else if (updatedUser) {
                return res.status(200).json({ user: updatedUser })
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are finding document by id, you are using new set with true to get updated document but where are  you updating the document.
There is update object that you need to pass to update the data
Link to docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

Comment: I'm updating via postman. Are you saying to pass the entire updated object here in this controller ?

Comment: well, then the issue is with your update method. That is not working as expected I guess.

Comment: It's just returning the same object. Nothing else.

Comment: You're correct. I needed to pass the updated object here. Good.